# App not visible when searched in Windows Phone store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

We are not able to search Windows Phone app from store; we can view the app from windows phone website

Please guide us to provide the solution

Comment: Did you make it market specific? Or hid it?

Comment: no we have not kept it market specific neither we have set hidden from store. we can browse the app from app store website but not from windows phone

Comment: It's hardly a programming question. I would follow such steps: check if it's set as hidden/beta, market specific, provide keywords in app information, wait few days, contact Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres an option to hide the app in store on developer dashboard - you might have mistakenly turned that on

EDIT:

If you have just published your app , wait for some time for it to become visible on Store on Phone

Comment: Well, people from the forums are not saying the same: http://forums.windowscentral.com/developers-corner/399199-microsoft-hidden-apps.html